# How to use @import for webfonts in HTML email?

Tags: html, css, email, webfonts

I am trying to get a hosted Avenir LT W01_55 Roman webfont to display in an HTML email for iOS devices.

The font is hosted here 'http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/af395689-2c2c-43f9-9e8f-68fdef40ecac.css'

I am using the @import method like this in the head  tags

```
'<style type="text/css">
     @import url('http://fast.fonts.net/cssapi/af395689-2c2c-43f9-9e8f-68fdef40ecac.css');

     td {
     font-family: 'Avenir LT W01_55 Roman', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
     .bold {
     font-family: 'Avenir LT W01_55 Roman', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}'
```

And reference it in the HTML content like this.

```
'<td style="border-collapse: collapse; font-family:'Avenir LT W01_55 Roman', Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:25px; line-height:34px; color:#1d1d1d;  margin:0;font-weight:bold;">'
```

It works on the web version but not after sending the test emails. Am I coding it incorrectly?

Comment: Are you coding this correctly - probably. Email clients are notorious for there support, or non-support, of HTML. You might want to have a look at this site (http://help.verticalresponse.com/how-to/tutorial/the_dos_and_donts_of_email_html/) for email do and dont.

Comment: Yes, many email clients will not support this webfont but I want to serve it to those who will be able to see it on iOS devices using this Campaign Monitor suggested method 'https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3897/using-web-fonts-in-email'